# Removing trailing zeros from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

If I have a list like

```
list1={2334.,342.,0.,0.,2322.,0.,0.,0.,0.,,,,,,};
```

it's easy to remove to trailing blanks with `Select[list1,NumberQ[#]&]`, and it's easy to remove all the zeroes, but how do I remove only the *trailing* zeros? I want to leave the mid-list zeroes in place.

Comment: There is `ImageCrop/ImageTrim`, `StringTrim` but no `ListTrim` :/ :)

Comment: @Kuba Don't give SW any ideas for "A new kind of list-manipulation" marketing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those trailing blanks are actually `Null`s (or `""` if you're using strings). The trailing nulls and zeros can be removed with patterns:

```
list1 /. {h__, (0 | 0. | Null) ...} :> {h}
(* {2334., 342., 0., 0., 2322.} *)
```

Comment: I suspect the OP just used the successive commas not to indicate `Null`s but rather that there were an unknown number of trailing `0`s.

Comment: @murray I don't think so, because in the next line they say that they remove the "blanks" with `Select` and `NumberQ`... you can't remove the zeros in this manner.

Comment: You may be right. I thought perhaps he was referring to the similar situation of deleting trailing "blanks" in a string.

Comment: Checking closely, it appears that some of the "Null" entries in my actual data are "", not Null. I adjusted your code accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If lists are large, something like

```
list1[[;; (Position[list1, Except[0 |0.| Null], 1][[-1, 1]])]]
```

should be quite a bit faster, e.g., a quick test on a 50K length list it is over 350X faster than the rule-based solution, and 4X faster than the `Take` solution.

If the list is "front-loaded" with values (i.e., more wanted than not), using

```
list1[[;; -Position[Reverse@list1, Except[List | 0 | 0. | Null], 1, 1][[1, 1]]]]
```

is thousands and hundreds of times faster than rule-based/take posted respectively.

If the lists are precisely the format in your example (desired, chunk of zeroes, chunk of nulls)

```
Flatten@Split[list1][[;; -3]]
```

is short, sweet, and very fast.

Answer (score 2):

```
Block[{Null = 0}, Internal`DeleteTrailingZeros @ Rationalize @ list1]
```

> {2334, 342, 0, 0, 2322}

```
1. %
```

> {2334., 342., 0., 0., 2322.}

Comment: Nice find.  Maybe post here too?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, done.